# Hiding some of query string in rack

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have written a sinatra app for displaying data from a database. The user can put a customer number into a form. This is then dealt with via a route `/customer/search` which captures the input of the forum via `params[:customer_number]`, processes it, and the results appear on the webpage.

What I would like to do, is tidy up the URL, so instead of saying

```
my_url/customer/search?customer_number=123456
```

It simply says

```
my_url/customer/?123456
```

I've seen this on other websites so it must be possible in general but is it possible with rack & sinatra?

My app is in the modular format, so the application is started by running `rackup config.ru`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
get '/customer/:customer_number'
```

?

You don't need parameters in query string at all (no `?` in the URL). In this case `customer_number` is a parameter from the URL.

Comment: `my_url/customer/?123456` still gives me what it did before - a Sinatra error message

Comment: Well, if you put a ?, those are query string parameters and are couples of key and values. Like, `my_url/customer/?customer_number=123456`. But I said, you don't need query string parameters. Get rid of that `?`

Comment: Ah! Yes, that works - I was hung up on this other app that has a `?`, but this is just as good. Problem now is what to do with the form where the user can put the customer number into? Do I have to re-engineer it to not be a form and just be a redirect to a URL instead? Or is there a cleverer/simpler option? The action is currently set to `/customer/search'

Comment: Mmm, I don't know if there is a better way but can you do a redirect? `redirect "/customer/#{params[:customer_number]}"`

Comment: I've made the button run some javascript which sends the user to the page, rather than be a submit button for the form. Seems to work fine. Thanks for your help.